# Configure Fluentbit "Docker Json parse depth"

Tags: fluent-bit

Using one of these parser plugin configurations:

```
[PARSER]
Name         docker
Format       json
Time_Key     time
Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
Time_Keep    On
# Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action
# =============|==================|=================
Decode_Field_As   escaped_utf8    log    do_next
Decode_Field_As   json       log

[PARSER]
Name        docker
Format      json
Time_Key    time
Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
Time_Keep   On
```

Is it possible to determine the depth to which the the plugin parses fields.

To make that more clear,
Let's say that you're trying to log an HTTP response from a Docker container containing a large body with multiple items.
Fluentbit should parse the Docker log, which it does. Great.
But it shouldn't be parsing the entire body as well.
I don't want 1000 fields in Elasticsearch, because it's trying to parse all items in my response body too.

```
{
  "length":"value",
  "timestamp":"timestamp",
  "items": [
     {...},
     {...},
     {...},
     ...
   ]
}
```

Is there any way to configure the depth to which Fluentbit will parse JSON?

Thanks!